# Using a type in place of a column definition list?

Tags: postgresql, datatypes, row, composite-types

Running the below, I get *"a column definition list is required for functions returning "record""*.

```
SELECT *
FROM json_to_record('{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4}');
ERROR:  a column definition list is required for functions returning "record"
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM json_to_record('{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4}');
```

That's fine. I know what it wants.

```
SELECT *
FROM json_to_record('{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4}')
  AS (a int, b int, c int, d int);
```

Also, In PostgreSQL, all tables already have a type created by the same name.

```
CREATE TABLE foo(a,b,c,d)
  AS VALUES
    (1,2,3,4);
```

That creates an internal type `foo` linked to the newly created table `foo`. I can easily create a similar type, `bar` explicitly though.

```
CREATE TYPE bar AS (a int, b int, c int, d int);
```

It would be great to be able to cast the record returned by `json_to_record()` to bar.

```
SELECT *
FROM json_to_record('{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4}')
  AS foo; -- bar? anything?
```

Is there anyway to satisfy a column definition list with a type?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `json_populate_record`:

```
SELECT *
FROM json_populate_record(null::foo, '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4}')
```

The column matching is done by name, non-existing columns are silently ignored:

```
create type other_foo as (a int, b int, x int, y int):
SELECT *
FROM json_populate_record(null::other_foo, '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4}');
```

returns:

```
a | b
--+--
1 | 2
```